# Unable to retrieve local storage variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am having an issue with the following code, I am trying to store a variable into local storage and then retrieve the variable from local storage...

Storing the contents of `.product-name h1`:

```
localStorage.productName = jQuery('.product-name h1').html();
```

Now I am trying to console.log the variable from local storage:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('productName'));
```

However when I console.log it sends back 'null', any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: [That works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/mqjznq54/). Try to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Open your page in chrome, hit [ctrl]+[shift]+i and check the local storage object in the resources tab to see if the correct value is being stored in the first place

Comment: It is a bit odd that you're using the property access mechanism when setting and the method access when getting. There's no reason to do that. I would tend to be consistent with what I used, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Put `console.log(jQuery('.product-name h1').html());` right before you set the value. I bet it shows `null`.

Comment: @Juhana: Good thought, but jQuery's `html` will never return `null`. It may return `undefined`, if there are no elements in the set, but never `null`. `undefined` would get converted to `"undefined"` and show up when being retrieved. Fundamentally, though, yes: Nicholas: Apply a debugger to the sitaution to find out what's going on.

Comment: @Juhana: Hah, but it could return `"null"`! E.g., `<div class="product-name"><h1>null</h1></div>`. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You seem to be correct! I tried it on the console on SO but they seem to be using some non-standard variation of jQuery.

Comment: @Juhana: Not nonstandard, just *really old*. They're using v1.7.1. Apparently, v1.7 returns `null` instead of `undefined` in this case, whereas more recent v1.x returns `undefined`. So if the OP is *also* using an outdated version, you could well be right!

Comment: @Juhana: Looks like that changed between the last release of v1.7 (1.7.2) and the first release of v1.8 (1.8.0). I'm guessing to make it be consistent with `val` and others.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) method in order to store some value into the  local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('productName', jQuery('.product-name h1').html());
```

Comment: @nnnnnn: Probably because `localStorage.productName = x` and `localStorage.setItem("productName", x)` do **exactly** the same thing. The only time you'd have to use `setItem` would be if you were dealing with a shim, which [you aren't on even vaguely-modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Ah. I didn't realise that would work. But then at my workplace I still (sometimes) have to cater to IE7 or IE8, so... maybe the OP is using an older browser?

Comment: @nnnnnn: IE8 has web storage. But if they're dealing with a really old thing like IE7 and using a shim, I'd expect them to say so. But since this is an ask-and-run... :-|